# Can custom domain names be used for beta SE sites?

Tags: discussion

If we propose a topic on area51, and it enters beta, can we use a custom domain and logo for it? Or are we only able to use the topic-title.stackexchange.com domain? Also, do we get the ability to edit the topic we proposed?

Comment: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/

Comment: Just to be sure: are you somehow under the impression that it will become your own site?

Comment: The only exception is when you get something like Canonical supporting Ask Ubuntu, which is a special case.

Comment: Ah, the faq on area51 doesn't state what happens after beta clearly. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not usually. It only happens if you have a really popular site, with support from the "man" (Stack Exchange Employees). However if you were referring to using **your** own domain, nope, it will never be your site.

However if a site gets out of beta mode, the community will choose logos, and such.

For more on why domain names are rarely used, please view [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/).

Comment: Jeff no longer works at Stack Exchange. I don't think he is a part of these decisions anymore.

Comment: @cpast He is still on the podcasts, and is still a mod on all the sites, but fair enough, i will edit.

Comment: @MarJamRob Confusing Joel and Jeff there? Haven't heard Jeff on the podcast recently.

Comment: @Bart Yuph... Thank you.